# Name of the math movie

Tags: reference-request, popular-math

Does anyone remember a movie about four mathematicians studying infinity, who ended up committing a suicide? It was aired online somewhere, and I can't find it (it's a documentary, if that helps).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you talking about **Dangerous Knowledge** by BBC? Though it's not quite about four mathematicians (at least one of the people was physicist), and not all of them were studying infinity directly. That's the only one that comes to my mind as I watched it a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you!

Comment: One seem to be able to [watch it](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-8492625684649921614) on Google video.

Answer (score 9):

**Dangerous Knowledge** it is!

Cantor - Infinity

Boltzmann - Entropy

Godel and Turing - Logic

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-5122859998068380459#

Comment: update link ? it's down